# Why my mmap in c is not working correctly?

Tags: c, process, fork, semaphore, mmap

I have got strange problem and need some help, 
I have tried to use rfork() to produce some child process, 
and useed mmap to map a shared memory, 
but it seems they didn't use the same memory space, but have their own,
 I don't know what's the reason, and the second question is, 
why the int tt becomes 4 after tt++,
but not 1?

thanks for your help!

This is my code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int *tt;

int main()
{
    tt = (int *)mmap (NULL, sizeof(int), O_RDONLY | O_RDWR, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    tt = 0;
    sem_t mutex;
    sem_init(&mutex,1,1);
    pid_t proc[2];
    int i, me = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
        if ((proc[i] = rfork(RFPROC)) == 0) {
            me = i;
            sem_wait(&mutex);
            printf("total: %d\n", tt);
            tt++;
            printf("total: %d\n", tt);
            sem_post(&mutex);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
total: 0
total: 4
total: 0
total: 4
```

Comment: Since your `mutex` is a local variable and not in the shared memory block, it won't actually synchronize the processes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the shared memory you have created by `tt = mmap( ... );` you have to use `*tt`:

```
 *tt = 0;
```

and

```
 printf("total: %d\n", *tt);
 (*tt)++;
```